# How can i do custom author list?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, list-authors

My blog have many author. I can list all author.

All Author list:

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_authors('exclude_admin=0&optioncount=1&show_fullname=1&hide_empty=1'); ?>
</ul>
```

But I want to sort in a special way.

For Example im currently viewing Tech category page, I want a list of author with these id (3,10,12). I will use this code in sidebar widget.
And i need a metabox for select author id.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you would be providing the author IDs in the widget options. And that the authors would be displayed in the order they were listed.

Assuming the input would be -> 3,10,12

You can have the following code to display the authors with that user ID in that order:

```
$user_ids = "3,10,12"; //this is assuming you already have the value stored in a variable

//convert the comma separated string into an array
$user_ids_array = explode(",", $user_ids);

//display the list of users
echo '<ul>';
foreach( $user_ids_array as $id ):
    $user = get_userdata( $id );
    echo '<li>'.$user->ID.' '.$user->display_name.'</li>';
endforeach;
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanx, its worked but i have a question again, how can i list it with author avatar?

Comment: You already have the user ID. Check out this function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
    // prepare arguments
    $args  = array(
    // search only for Authors role
    'role' => 'Author',
    // order results by display_name
    'orderby' => 'display_name'

//add your custom meta key query here

    );
    // Create the WP_User_Query object
    $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
    // Get the results
    $authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();
    // Check for results
    if (!empty($authors))
    {
        echo '<ul>';
        // loop trough each author
        foreach ($authors as $author)
        {
            // get all the user's data
            $author_info = get_userdata($author->ID);
            echo '<li>'.$author->ID.' '.$author_info->first_name.' '.$author_info->last_name.'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo 'No authors found';
    }
```

For more reference see [this](http://mattvarone.com/wordpress/list-users-with-wp_user_query/).

Comment: Hello, thnx for answer but i need custom solution. i don't know very good PHP.